# Java swing cell renderer based on column class

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

In Java Swing we have a `JTable`, `TableModel`, `ColumnModel` and a `TableCellRenderer` which work together to display a table.

How can I provide customisation to get a custom cell renderer based on a column class - as opposed to setting the renderer based on column index.

```
final JTable table = new JTable(model);
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(new DateTimeRenderer());
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(new SuperDuperDoubleCellRenderer());
```

Suppose I have 20 numeric cells in there!!!

The above works, but I am not so keen on that solution as it would change when the model changed - so it isn't well encapsulated to that extent - this is client code.

The `TableModel` understands the underlying table data structure where it can do the custom mapping to a complex type (as opposed to DefaultTableModel and Vectors) - where it knows the data types of how each column.

```
public class DemoTableModel implements TableModel {
    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        // date time, double, etc...
        return columnInfo.get(columnIndex).getDataType();
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is to tell a `JTable`, hey the column class (returned from the table model) is a custom DateTime type - use the `CustomDateTimeCellRenderer`.  If it is a double, then use the custom `SuperDuperDoubleCellRenderer`.

The trouble is digging through the sources to see where this behaviour marries up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I would like to do is to tell a JTable, hey the column class (returned from the table model) is a custom DateTime type - use the CustomDateTimeCellRenderer. If it is a double, then use the custom SuperDuperDoubleCellRenderer.

You set the renderer at the table level by specifying the class and renderer:

```
table.setDefaultRenderer(Double.class, yourDoubleCellRenderer);
table.setDefaultRenderer(CustomDateTime.class, yourCustomDateTimeRenderer);
```

Comment: Bah! I didn't see the param for a class. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this at the `CellRenderer` level - cell renderers are only required to implement

```
Component getTableCellRendererComponent​(JTable table,
                                    Object value,
                                    boolean isSelected,
                                    boolean hasFocus,
                                    int row,
                                    int column)
```

Nothing stops you from telling the whole JTable to render cells using a, say, `SmartCellRenderer` that looks at the type of the passed-in value and delegates actual rendering to a `DoubleCellRenderer`, a `StringCellRenderer`, or a `CuteInternetCatRenderer`. Assuming object types are unique, this should be easy to do (if somewhat ugly because of the set of `if (value instanceof InternetCat) { ... }` that decides how to render each object based on its class).

A better solution (no ugly `instanceof`s required) is to assign specific renderers to specific columns at column insertion time:

```
 // model index 0, width 75, renderer to use, editor to use
 myTable.getColumnModel().addColumn(0, 75, cuteInternetCatRenderer, null);
```

Comment: Yeah, my concern was firing up a new instance of JTables across the board and having this logic repeated in them.  I guess having an abstraction around this behaviour makes sense rather than each client adding all of the default cell renderers in.

Comment: The typical way to do it is to subclass the default `JTable` to, say, a `CatTable` - and only create instances of that subclass, which encapsulates all your business-specific JTable needs and customizations. Such as, say, custom cell renderers.